# How do French people typically say, 'from all the odds and ends we had lying around'?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

I'm not sure a French expression matching with this exists but French language is rich in the scope of their expressions, so I must try. What is a typical way to say, 'from all the odds and ends we had lying around', like in a sewing situation as follows?

'Considering we just stitched them together from all the odds and ends we had lying around, they look well professional.'

Answer (score 3):

For sewing specifically, you can use [*chute* (II.A.3)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chute), meaning a small piece of cloth that remains after cutting a large piece to the shape needed to make something.

*Compte tenu du fait que nous les avons cousus à partir des chutes qui nous restaient, le résultat est remarquablement professionnel.*
*Pour des vêtements faits avec les chutes que nous avions sous la main, ils ont l'air remarquablement professionnels.*

For something like furniture, you can use the expression [*de bric et de broc*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_bric_et_de_broc).

*Cette chambre est meublée de bric et de broc, avec un peu tout ce que nous avons pu récupérer. Le résultat est pourtant très professionnel.*
*Ce meuble est fait de bric et de broc, avec des morceaux de bois récupérés par-ci par-là. Le résultat est pourtant très professionnel.*

The verb *récupérer* in this sense is a natural way of expressing that you took materials that were available, as opposed to purchasing new materials.

Answer (score 2):

In conversation, one of the phrasings that come naturally to me in an instance like this is:

> Quand on pense qu’on les a cousus **avec tout ce qui nous tombait sous la main**, le résultat est assez professionnel.

I get the impression that you are looking for a noun that is equivalent to "*odds and ends*", but "*tomber sous la main (de qqn.)*" conveys the idea of "*making do with what little we have here*" well enough. The less wordy, the better.

Comment: Je dirais « avec un peu tout ce qui … » ou « avec ce qui … », pas juste « tout ».

Answer (score -2):

Apparently the expressions that correspond are not fixed syntagms in French; there is however a fixed  expressions that comes quite close; the [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/odds%20and%20ends/forced) dictionary confirms that; this is "bric à brac".

- Compte tenu que nous les avons assemblés à partir de  bric à brac sur lequel nous pouvions mettre la main, ils ont une belle apparence.

Nevertheless there is also an adverbial expression that is quite accurate as a French equivalent : "de bric et de broc".

- Compte tenu que nous les avons assemblés de bric et de broc en utilisant ce que nous avions sous la main, ils ont une belle apparence.

Comment: @user17522 I can't pretend I have at my command **all** the possible ways to render that English sentence into French, and in particular all the possible way in a well articulated French fit for  a decent letter or a neat conversation, but those two sentences do belong to that type of language; sorry to disappoint you in asseverating that.

Comment: Neither sentence is quite correct. You can say « nous les avons assemblés à partir du bric à brac … » or « nous avons assemblé le bric à brac », but « assembler de » doesn't fit. The phrase « de bric et de broc » is mostly a set phrase used with *faire*, and it means « ce que nous avions sous la main » : « En tenant compte du fait qu'ils sont fait de bric et de broc, ils ont une belle apparence ».

Comment: @Gilles Maintenant que l'on me le montre il me semble bien que « du » ne serait pas correct et « à partir » est tout à fait clair ; c'est ce que je pensais dire. Je ne suis pas d'accord cependant avec un supposé effet pléonastique dans la  seconde phrase ; le TLFi a pour définition «  (Constitué) d'éléments de nature diverse et de toute provenance. » : on n'a pas nécessairement les éléments sous la main.

Comment: @Gilles On trouve dans la littérature « construit/habillé de bric et de broc » et même «  cahute de planches qu'il avait assemblées de bric et de broc ».

Comment: @Fólkvangr Il vous manque un sens, plus général, qui n'a rien à voir avec le temps : (TLFi) c) En prenant comme origine logique. À partir **d'éléments préexistants**, de principes établis. ex. tirés  dictionnaire Ac. : Dans la locution prépositive « À partir de ». Une fortune édifiée à partir de rien. En usant de, en se servant de. Un mot formé à partir de deux racines grecques. On crée de nombreux adverbes à partir d'adjectifs. Du papier fabriqué à partir de chiffons. _ Avant de tailler allègrement dans le total des points d'un utilisateur essayez de vous assurer de ce que vous avancez !

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je n'ai pas à faire *votre* travail de vérification ; c'est à vous en premier lieu de faire le nécessaire ; si vous ne pouvez pas accéder au TLFi et au dictionnaire de l'Ac. avec vos propres moyens je ne vois pas comment vous pouvez faire grand chose d'autre.

Comment: @Fólkvangr **Mon** expression ? Vous passez complètement à côté de l'idée centrale dans « Considering we just stitched them together from all the odds and ends we had lying around, they look well professional. ».

Comment: @Fólkvangr Vous sélectionnez la partie qui sert votre argument et ne voyez pas l'autre qui partie qui contredit cet argument ? Lisez donc le tout : à partir de **deux** racines, à partir de chiffon**s**; il y a plusieurs choses, comme dans le bric à brac.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Voilà un point de vue intéressant, malheureusement il ne prend en compte que la moitié de la définition de « bric-à-brac » qui est « **Ensemble d'objets** de peu de valeur et de provenance diverse, **présenté** dans le plus grand désordre ». Donc le terme n'est pas de la sorte qui décrive principalement une façon de disposer les choses mais il est de la sorte qui décrit principalement un ensemble.   La dernière possibilité, en elle-même, me laisse perplexe, cependant (assembler à partir de désordre); « réorganiser à partir d'un désordre » semble assez logique.